# Can you constrain a type by the size of the data in the type?

Tags: swift, types, constraints

I was messing around with matrix operations (it was the first programming I ever did nearly 20 years ago) and wanted to recreate what I had done all that time ago but with more modern practices.

Anyway...

One of the constraints with matrix operations is that the size of the matrices involved in the operations matter.

i.e. for addition the two matrices must be of the same size. i.e. M(i, j) + N(i, j). And multiplication only works if the number of columns of the left matrix is the same as the number of rows of the right matrix, etc...

I was looking for ways that I could apply these constraints at compile time but I'm not sure if that's possible.

I know I could create different subtypes for each size of matrix (Matrix1x1, Matrix1x2, Matrix2x3, ...) but there are "quite a lot" of those so that's a non-starter.

I could also use a precondition on the function which checks the input matrices for the correct sizes before doing anything (a bit like index out of bounds check on an array).

But I was wondering if there was a way of applying the `size` of the matrix to the `type` of the matrix at all. I don't think I've heard of this before but wanted to check before throwing out the idea entirely.

Something akin to when I create the matrix it applies the fact that it knows at that point what size the matrix has.

The function definition might then look something like...

`func add(m: Matrix<i, j>, n: Matrix<i, j>) -> Matrix<i, j>`

and

`func multiply(m: Matrix<i, j>, n: Matrix<k, i>) -> Matrix<j, k>` // or something

Where `i` and `j` are not generic type constraints but size constraints. But that isn't valid syntax just give the general idea of what I'm thinking.

Comment: Sadly this isn't possible in Swift at the moment. Since the sizes can only be known at runtime, even though from the time of initialisation they are constant, the type system cannot know about these runtime values. This is [possible in other languages, such as Haskell](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/fixed-list-0.1.6/docs/Data-FixedList.html), so hopefully once Swift will get there as well.

Comment: @DávidPásztor oh, that's excellent, thanks! I'm glad I wasn't going off on a completely wrong tangent. Time for me to maybe start playing around with Haskell. :)

Comment: Would the down voter care to explain why this was down voted? Happy to update the question.